# Nuxt Vuex State and Getters Has Data But Grayed Out

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I was trying to pull data out of getters with a v-for but I kept getting nothing back so I decided to console log 'this.$store.getters.tiers' and it came back undefined.

The data shows up in the Vue Browser tab, but both State and Getters appear grayed out unless I manually click on that arrow. Is the blank data related to this, or something that I forgot in my code?

Thanks for the help!

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

computed: {
    tiers() {
      return this.$store.getters.tiers;
    },
    ...mapGetters(["loggedInUser"])
  },
```

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: () => ({
    tiers: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Director Subscription",
        price: 25
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Regular Subscription",
        price: 10
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Regular+ Subscription",
        price: 15
      }
    ],
    StoreCart: []
  }),
  getters: {
    tiers: state => state.tiers,
    StoreCart: state => state.StoreCart
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_Item(state, id) {
      state.StoreCart.push(id);
    },
    REMOVE_Item(state, index) {
      state.StoreCart.splice(index, 1);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    addItem(context, id) {
      context.commit("ADD_Item", id);
    },
    removeItem(context, index) {
      context.commit("REMOVE_Item", index);
    }
  },
  modules: {}
});

export const getters = {
  isAuthenticated(state) {
    return state.auth.loggedIn;
  },
  loggedInUser(state) {
    return state.auth.user;
  }
};
```

[image: Grayed out with the 'Load state' button]

Comment: please post the full store and the full component. first thing I see is your vuex store's state is a function returning an object but with vuex 3.x for vue 2 state just needs to be an object. you could also map tiers in using mapGetters as well instead of recreating it like you are (...mapGetters(["loggedInUser", "tiers"]), but that's probably not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: Figured it out!**

I'm running Nuxt and after revising the docs, I realized that the framework already builds a lot of the objects that would otherwise need to be created when using vanilla Vuex. Below is the correct way to set up the store!

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
Vue.use(Vuex);

export const state = () => ({
  tiers: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Director Subscription",
      price: 25
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Regular Subscription",
      price: 10
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Regular+ Subscription",
      price: 15
    }
  ],
  StoreCart: []
});

export const mutations = {
  ADD_Item(state, id) {
    state.StoreCart.push(id);
  },
 
  REMOVE_Item(state, index) {
    state.StoreCart.splice(index, 1);
  }
};
export const actions = {
  addItem(context, id) {
    context.commit("ADD_Item", id);
  },
  removeItem(context, index) {
    context.commit("REMOVE_Item", index);
  }
};


export const getters = {
  isAuthenticated(state) {
    return state.auth.loggedIn;
  },
  loggedInUser(state) {
    return state.auth.user;
  },
  tiers: state => state.tiers,
  StoreCart: state => state.StoreCart
};
```